# XMLStreamException: No element was found to write: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while parsing xml file using StAX

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax, stax

In below xml file I have File name and its respective rule numbers in hashmap(named 'ds' in source code) in format {{file1.c,{1234,3456,5087,9900,....}},{file2.c,{1234,3456,5087,9900,....}}>, if for file1.c any rule number in given list exists in xml file for `<QACRule>` tag (here 5087 is matching) I want to delete its parent node i.e. `<Complain>` node.

```
<SourceFiles>
    **<File name="file1.c">**
        <FileSummary>
            <QAC>
                <StatDev>0</StatDev>
                <StatIntendDev>1</StatIntendDev>
            </QAC>
            <Developer>
                <StatDev>0</StatDev>
                <StatIntendDev>0</StatIntendDev>
                <StatBlank>1</StatBlank>
            </Developer>
            <Total>
                <TotalRank>intended deviation</TotalRank>
                <StatDev>0</StatDev>
                <StatIntendDev>1</StatIntendDev>
            </Total>
        </FileSummary>
        **<Complain lfd="1">**
            <Line>43</Line>
            <Description>"#include statements"</Description>
            <Rule>
                **<QACRule>5087</QACRule>**
                <CodingStd>18.1.</CodingStd>
                <Deviation>true</Deviation>
            </Rule>
            <Ranking>
                <QACRank>intended deviation</QACRank>
                <DeveloperRank></DeveloperRank>
                <TotalRank>intended deviation</TotalRank>
            </Ranking>
            <Comment>these includes must stay here at this position</Comment>
        </Complain>
        **<Complain lfd="2">**
            <Line>140</Line>
            <Description>"#include statements"</Description>
            <Rule>
                **<QACRule>55555</QACRule>**
                <CodingStd>18.1.</CodingStd>
                <Deviation>true</Deviation>
            </Rule>
            <Ranking>
                <QACRank>intended deviation</QACRank>
                <DeveloperRank></DeveloperRank>
                <TotalRank>intended deviation</TotalRank>
             </Ranking>
             <Comment>these includes must stay here at this position</Comment>
        </Complain>
    </File>
    <File name="file2.c>
         ......
    </File>
</SourceFiles>
```

but I'm not understanding the thing that after checking `<QACRule>` value in hashmap how can I go above and delete the `<Complain>` node ?

I tried following java code:

```
inFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
outFactory= XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
eventReader = inFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileReader(inputFilePath));
out=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\uidg8154\\Desktop\\new.xml");
eventWriter= outFactory.createXMLEventWriter(out);
while(eventReader.hasNext()){
    XMLEvent event=eventReader.nextEvent();

    if(event.isStartElement() && event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("SourceFiles") ){
        isSourceFileParent=true;    
        System.out.println("-------start of <SourceFies>---------");
        srcFiles=new SourceFiles();
    }

    if(event.isEndElement() && event.asEndElement().getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("SourceFiles")){
        isSourceFileParent=false;
        System.out.println("-------end of <SourceFies>---------");

    }

    if(isSourceFileParent==true && event.isStartElement() && event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("File")){
            fileNameValue=event.asStartElement().getAttributeByName(new QName("name")).getValue();
        System.out.println(fileNameValue);
        sourceFileNamesFromInputXml.add(fileNameValue);
    }

    if(isSourceFileParent==true && event.isStartElement() && event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("Complain")){ 
        complainIdValue=event.asStartElement().getAttributeByName(new QName("lfd")).getValue();
        System.out.println(complainIdValue);
    }

    if(isSourceFileParent==true && event.isStartElement() && event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("QACRule")){ 
        event = eventReader.nextEvent();
        isQacRuleParent=true;
        isProceed=true;
        qacRuleNoValue=event.asCharacters().getData();
    }

    if(ds.containsKey(fileNameValue) && isProceed==true){
        qacRuleNos=ds.get(fileNameValue);
        if(qacRuleNos.contains(qacRuleNoValue)){
            isIgnoreComplainNode=true;
        }
    }

    if (isSourceFileParent==true && event.isEndElement() && event.asEndElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("Complain") && isIgnoreComplainNode==true) {
        isIgnoreComplainNode=false;
    }

    if(isIgnoreComplainNode==false){
        System.out.println(event);
        eventWriter.add(event);
    }
}//end of while
eventWriter.flush();
eventWriter.close();
```

with this code I'm facing "javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: No element was found to write: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1"  exception and wierdly written output file.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the stax parsing and writing at the same time, you may need to handle a bit more of context. When you detected that `isIgnoreComplainNode=true`, it is already too late as you already wrote on the output the event corresponding to :

```
<Complain lfd="1">
        <Line>43</Line>
        <Description>"#include statements"</Description>
        <Rule>
            <QACRule>
```

If you want to avoid these events in your output, you should collect the events between `<Complain>` opening until `</Complain>` closure in a List, when you reach `<Complain>` closure: check `isIgnoreComplainNode` :

- if false, then add all the events of the list into the eventWriter (in the same order)
- if true, do nothing

clear the list and keep parsing.

The main question is rather "how can I avoid writing unwanted `<Complain>` node in my output" that "how can I go above and delete the `<Complain>` node". If you send the event to the eventWriter, it is too late to come back.